# Android Wear custom notification layout when minimized

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I've been trying for a while to replicate some of the demo notifications from the Android Wear app with custom layouts, but there is one thing I can't get working: **showing the custom layout when the notification is *minimized*.** I'm using the `setDisplayIntent()` method to embed an activity into the notification with custom a layout.

The thing is, when the notification is expanded the activity's layout is displayed properly. But then the notification minimizes the activity is hidden and the default notification data is displayed (`contentTitle`, `contentText`).

I'm displaying the notification with `setDisplayIntent()` from the wear application as shown here:

```java
Intent page1Intent = new Intent(context, Page1Activity.class);
Notification page1notif = new Notification.Builder(context)
  .setContentTitle("Notification title")
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_renfe)
  .extend(new Notification.WearableExtender()
    .setBackground(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.train_background))
    .setDisplayIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, page1Intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
    .setCustomSizePreset(Notification.WearableExtender.SIZE_LARGE))
  .build();
```

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: wear notification]

And here's what I've got:
[image: my notification]

What kind of sorcery is Google doing to show their demo cards? Is there something from the API that I've missed or are they using a different technique?

Thanks!